# Bing architecture and how it works underneath?

Tags: architecture, bing

Could someone please explain how Bing.com works underneath and what is it's architecture?

1. Implementation (languages used)
2. Brief description of algorithm approach
3. Hardware it runs on
4. Approaches for scalability

Answer (score 3):

That isn't the type of stuff anybody here can tell you. Even if an employee working on the Bing project were here, there would most certainly be ND's preventing them from discussing it. That being said, if you want to study large-scale search engines, there's a slew of papers available via [a quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22google+architecture%22&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g5) on Google's Architecture.